# Sequence of elements in a list satisfying a condition

Tags: python, list

Assume I have a list of this type:

```
#    0   1  2  3   4  5  6  7  8  9   10  11 -- list index
li=[-1, -1, 2, 2, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 ]
```

I want to find each index for which the value is the same for the `n` following indices.

I can do it (laboriously) this way:

```
def sub_seq(li,n):
    ans={}
    for x in set(li):
        ans[x]=[i for i,e in enumerate(li[:-n+1]) if all(x==y for y in li[i:i+n])]

    ans={k:v for k,v in ans.items() if v}

    return ans

li=[-1, -1, 2, 2, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1] 
for i in (5,4,3,2):
    print i, sub_seq(li,i)
```

Prints:

```
5 {1: [5]}
4 {1: [5, 6]}
3 {1: [5, 6, 7]}
2 {1: [5, 6, 7, 8], 2: [2], -1: [0, 10]}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean better as in less CPU time, or better in terms of readability?

Comment: Ideomatic and readable I suppose.

Comment: Are the values of the list limited to integers -1, 1, 2 or can they any value or any type?

Comment: They can be any hashable value. ie, not a sub list or something like that. integer, float, string types

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Analyzing data is typically easier if you first convert it to a convenient form.  In this case, a [run-length-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) would be a good starting point:

```
from itertools import groupby, accumulate
from collections import defaultdict

def sub_seq(li, n):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    rle = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(li)]
    endpoints = accumulate(size for k, size in rle)
    for end_index, (value, count) in zip(endpoints, rle):
        for index in range(end_index - count, end_index - n + 1):
            d[value].append(index)
    return dict(d)
```

Comment: How would I roll the indicies into the tuple returned by groupby?

Comment: Note: `itertools.accumulate()` is for Python 3.2+ (the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) gives equivalent code). NumPy has the equivalent `numpy.cumsum()`.

Answer (score 1):

As Raymond Hettinger points out in his answer, [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) makes easier to check consecutive values. If you also enumerate the list, you can keep the corresponding indices and add them to the dictionary (I use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make the function as short as possible):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import defaultdict

li = [-1, -1, 2, 2, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1]

def sub_seq(li, n):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for k, g in groupby(enumerate(li), itemgetter(1)):
        l = list(map(itemgetter(0), g))
        if n <= len(l): res[k] += l[0:len(l)-n+1]
    return res

for i in (5,4,3,2):
    print i, sub_seq(li,i)
```

Which prints:

```
5 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [5]})
4 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [5, 6]})
3 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [5, 6, 7]})
2 defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [5, 6, 7, 8], 2: [2], -1: [0, 10]})
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that this is a bit more readable, constructs less objects and I would guess runs faster.

```
li=[-1, -1, 2, 2, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1 ]

results = []
i = 0
while i < len(li):
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(li) and li[i] == li[j]:
        j += 1
    results.append((i,li[i],j-i))
    i = j

print results #[(0, -1, 2), (2, 2, 2), (4, -1, 1), (5, 1, 5), (10, -1, 2)]
```

Comment: That is giving me different result really. ie, it is important for me to know that the x[i+j]==y[i+j+1], is satisfied at 3 different indices. Not necessarily overlapping. If I am looking for a sequence 3 elements long, I don't care if there is one 2 elements long.

Comment: `filter(lambda x: x[2] > n,results)` or do the checking before you append results.